# How can I reference a class in an array?

Tags: java

Im having a problem with something that I find really hard to explain but ill try my best.

I was wondering if there was any way I could store a class in an array or some sort of reference to the class in the array. I want to be able to do something like

```
array[3].run();
```

But I'm stuck and have no idea what to do. Currently I'm using a messy method which is like this

```
public static void methodName(String s) {
    if(s.equals("string")) String.run();
    if(s.equals("int")) Integer.run();
}
```

I don't like this as its messy and I feel there must be a better way. Is there? Is what I am trying to do possible?

Comment: If they are not builtin classes, why not implement `Runnable`? Then u can put all of them in `Runnable[]` array.

Comment: @VenkataRaju Can you show me how to do that as an answer please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they are not builtin classes, all of them can implement `Runnable`. Then you can put all of them in `Runnable[]` array.

Something like this:

```
class MyClass1 implements Runnable { /* code here */ }
class MyClass2 implements Runnable { /* code here */ }

Runnable[] runnables = { new MyClass1(), new MyClass2() };

for (Runnable runnable : runnables)
  runnable.run();
```

Comment: Simple and elegant. +1.

Comment: One change I made though, Instead of using the runnable interface i just made my own interface with some custom methods.

Comment: @Hamish Now, with Java 8 method handles even custom methods should work fine with existing interfaces. As long as the method input parameters matches  `e.g. String str = "Hello"; Runnable[] rs = { str::toUpperCase, str::length };`